# TFS display names changed after 2010 to 2013 migration with server move

Tags: tfs, active-directory, migration

After performing a migration from TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 our users started encountering issues modifying work items (`___ is not in the list of supported values`). After investigating we found that for all of our users, the display name presented by TFS no longer matches that in the active directory. Specifically, the `[]/\` characters seem to be being removed when the AD sync process occurs. A specific example can be seen below.

```
Collection table ADObjects and Configuration table tbl_Identity, Column DisplayName

After Migration to TFS 2013
Karloff, Dave PCS TRW CAN

Before Migration to TFS 2013
Karloff, Dave [PCS/TRW/CAN]
```

Has anyone encountered this error or have any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design an TFS no longer supports those characters in the users name. Some of this came in 2012 and the rest in 2013.

Comment: Thank you @MrHinsh. I found a link describing this issue here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/db17f4d7-6435-4321-a2ac-9dda5460ac9a/tfs-user-display-name-restrictions-are-stronger-than-ad-user-display-name-restrictions-causing?forum=tfsintegration